# DownloadUrl is empty for File for Some Files

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

When I am trying to retrieve metadata using Google Drive .Net Api , I am able to retrieve Document Title but DownloadUrl for File is empty , whereaas if I upload a new file then its available.

This is the Code I am using..

```
Try
            Dim authenticator As IAuthenticator = TryCast(Session("authenticator"), IAuthenticator)
            Dim service As DriveService = TryCast(Session("Service"), DriveService)
            If authenticator Is Nothing OrElse service Is Nothing Then
                Return Json("Failed Authenticator", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
            End If
            Dim file As Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File = service.Files.Get(file_id).Fetch()
              Return Json(file.DownloadUrl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Json(ex.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        End Try
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documents in Google native formats do not include a `downloadUrl`, for them you should use the  `exportLinks` collection instead.

For more details on how to download files from Drive, please check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads